# Find attribute names that start with a certain pattern

Tags: xpath

I am looking to find all attributes of an element that match a certain pattern.

So for an element

```
<element s2="1" name="aaaa" id="1" />
<element s3="1" name="aaaa" id="2" />
```

I would like to be able to find all attributes that start with 's' (returning the value of **s1** for the first element and **s3** for the value of the second element).

If this is outside of xpath's ability please let me know.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Use**:

```
element/@*[starts-with(name(), 's')]
```

This XPath expression selects all atribute nodes whose name starts with the string `'s'` and that are attributes of elements named `element` that are children of the current node.

`starts-with()` is a standard function in XPath 1.0

Comment: Works as advertised and helped me get the original answer working as well.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the question and an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
element/@*[substring(name(), 1,1) = "s"]
```

will match any attribute that starts with 's'.

The function `starts-with()` might look better than using `substring()`

Comment: Hmmm using this in XMLSpy, which is my go-to application for Xpath I am getting an error "Unexpected token - "[substring(name(), 1,1) =".

Comment: This definitely looks like the approach I need so many thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks to Dimitrie the following substring pattern works also element/@*[substring(name(),1,1) = 's']

Comment: @Dunderklumpen: Actually, the XPath expression I came up with is: `element/@*[starts-with(name(), 's')]`

Comment: You need to correct your Expression -- right now it isn't syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested the given answers from both **@Dimitre-Novatchev** and **@Ledhund**, using **lxml.html** module in **Python**.

Both `element/@*[starts-with(name(), 's')]` and `element/@*[substring(name(), 1,1) = "s"]` return only the **values** of *s2* and *s3*. You won't be able to know which value belong to which attribute.

I think in practice I would be more interested in finding the elements themselves that contain the attributes of names starting with specific characters rather than just their values.

To achieve that is very simple, just add `/..` at the end,

`element/@*[starts-with(name(), "s")]/..`

or

`element/@*[starts-with(name(), "s")]/parent::*`

or

`element/@*[starts-with(name(), "s")]/parent::node()`

Answer (score 0):

None from above worked for me.
So I did not some changes and it worked for me. :)

```
/*:UserCustomField[starts-with(@name, 'purchaseDate')]
```