# How to put all WSDL complextypes in one package and simpletypes in another package using CXF WSDL2JAVA JAXB external binding file approach?

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

**Requirement :** generating java artifacts(classes) & packaging all complextypes to one package and all simple types to other package from wsdl using CXF WSDL2JAVA JAXB external binding file approach. I was struck with XPATH syntaxes in JAXB external binding file.
Please help me regarding this.

Thank you ..

Comment: Did you mean to post the actual xml/bindings ? That would make it A LOT easier to help you here.

Comment: @PatriceM. Hi Patrice, in JAXB external binding file i need the node  xpath syntax to get all complextypes of wsdl. i found one link related to my query..i am sharing the link.                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150510/find-attribute-names-that-start-with-a-certain-pattern.....................                                                                        please modify it and post the code which will work in my scenario. thank u...