# XPath: Query multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Can i query multiple attributes from a XML Node by using XPath?
Especially from sub-nodes?
e.g.

```
<outer>
  <inner attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
      <leaf attr3="value3" />
  </inner>
  <inner attr1="value1Inner1" attr2="valueInner12">
      <leaf attr3="value_leaf2" />
  </inner>
</outer>
```

I want to get something like

```
[
  ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
  ["value1Inner1", "valueInner12", value_leaf2"]
]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find attribute names that start with a certain pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150510/find-attribute-names-that-start-with-a-certain-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, attributes are just nodes. But it can not fetch nested node lists. So for the desired result you need to select the `inner` elements first. Iterate them and fetch all the attribute from them and their descendants.

Fetch the `inner? element nodes:

`/outer/inner`

And the attributes of the context node and its descendants:

`descendant-or-self::*/@*`

Demo:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<outer>
  <inner attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
      <leaf attr3="value3" />
  </inner>
  <inner attr1="value1Inner1" attr2="valueInner12">
      <leaf attr3="value_leaf2" />
  </inner>
</outer>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/outer/inner') as $inner) {
  $attributes = array_map(
    function (DOMAttr $node) {
      return $node->value;
    },
    iterator_to_array(
      $xpath->evaluate('descendant-or-self::*/@*', $inner)
    )
  );
  var_dump($attributes);
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "value3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "value1Inner1"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "valueInner12"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "value_leaf2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
//*/@*[starts-with(name(), 'attr')]
```

This query matches any node that has an atribute starting with `attr`.

[DEMO](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%3Couter%3E%0A%20%20%3Cinner%20attr1%3D%22value1%22%20attr2%3D%22value2%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cleaf%20attr3%3D%22value3%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Finner%3E%0A%20%20%3Cinner%20attr1%3D%22value1Inner1%22%20attr2%3D%22valueInner12%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cleaf%20attr3%3D%22value_leaf2%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Finner%3E%0A%3C%2Fouter%3E&extract=%2F%2F*%2F%40*[starts-with(name()%2C%20%27attr%27)]%0A&extract-kind=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)