# How to select xmlnode from its key using XPATH

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Here is my XML file

```
 <Drive>
    <Data0 Key="1" Name="AA" />
    <Data1 Key="2" Name="BB" />
    <Data2 Key="4" Name="CC" />
    <Data3 Key="10" Name="WW" />
    <Data4 Key="11" Name="WE" />
    <Data5 Key="12" Name="VW" />
    </Drive>
```

I want to select all nodes where their [Key] start with "1" using C# and XML XPATH

I tried this:

```
XmlNodeList FKNodes = node.SelectNodes("*/* [@Key like '1*']")
```

Comment: Hi ! What did you try ? Can you show it ?

Comment: see update of my question

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151347/4045532) is probably what you want.

Comment: I do not know the element name it is dynamic

Comment: Something like `Drive//@*[starts-with(@Key, '1')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` to select element of any name, and use [`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function to match the `Key` attribute value partially :

```
XmlNodeList FKNodes = node.SelectNodes("//*[starts-with(@Key, '1')]")
```

**<kbd>[`xpath demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/m9cEsfubL)</kbd>**

Comment: where can I find all functions like starts-with() !

Comment: @Michaagus added a link to the official specification. You can find other XPath 1.0 functions there.. And this is an alternative link by MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions